# Unable to install Elasticsearch on Mac Sierra (10.12.2)

Tags: java, elasticsearch, homebrew, macos-sierra

When attempting to start Elasticsearch 5.1.1 via

`$ elasticsearch`

I get the output:

`Error: Could not find or load main class -Xms2g`

I've looked into:

1. I read it may be an error in how a class is called? But I'm not exposed to doing that. This [thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/java-classloader-not-able-to-load-error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class/25016) doesn't help and isn't really my problem as I'm not installing a plugin.
2. I installed via Homebrew. Here is some output from that:

   ```
   $ brew info elasticsearch
   elasticsearch: stable 5.1.1, HEAD
   Distributed search & analytics engine
   https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch
   Conflicts with: elasticsearch@1.7, elasticsearch@2.4
   /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/5.1.1 (98 files, 35.2M) *
     Built from source on 2016-12-14 at 09:23:56
   From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/elasticsearch.rb
   ==> Requirements
   Required: java >= 1.8 ✔
   ==> Caveats
   Data:    /usr/local/var/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_GabbAHH/
   Logs:    /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_GabbAHH.log
   Plugins: /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/5.1.1/libexec/plugins/
   Config:  /usr/local/etc/elasticsearch/
   plugin script: /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/5.1.1/libexec/bin/plugin

   To have launchd start elasticsearch now and restart at login:
     brew services start elasticsearch
   Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
     elasticsearch

   $ brew doctor
   Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
   with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
   working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!
   Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
   Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
   those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run `brew link` on these:
     mongodb
     ruby
   ```
3. I also tried originally installing via [manually extracting the .tar.gz package](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_installation.html). I at first got some Java permission denied errors, but after running a `chown` to admin for myself I also got this same `Error: Could not find or load main class` type error.
4. I just updated my Java JDK to the latest: 1.8.0_112 and set my JAVA_HOME variable to that directory accordingly.
5. The most recent version of Elasticsearch 2 (2.4.3) works. Meanwhile, Elasticsearch v5.0.2 fails.

What can I do to have Elasticsearch properly installed on my Mac?

Comment: Maybe spaces in your path? Broken environment (check `set | grep ^ES_`)? If you want to debug it, find the start script and echo the command that it's executing to start the process.

Comment: @teppic Can you please explain what the `set` command is supposed to do? Is something supposed to be set to something else here?

Comment: It will list any environment variables that start with ES_. Elasticsearch uses them to set up its start script. There will probably be none. If there are they could be the cause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely have a problem in your .bash_profile. Usually elastic starts out of the box on a mac.

Answer (score 5):

Watch out with this line in your `.bashrc` or similar:

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'
```

That will break many shell's pipes, so many runners will fail without giving you any clue.

Distros as Ubuntu usually have this enabled by default for system users. Be careful and check that shell environment variable.

This problem was solved on my servers by just unsetting this variable.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do to make upgrading and using multiple projects on my machine is using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

CURRENT_PROJECT=$(pwd)
CONFIG=$CURRENT_PROJECT/config
DATA=$CURRENT_PROJECT/data
LOGS=$CURRENT_PROJECT/logs

BASH_ES_OPTS="-Epath.conf=$CONFIG -Epath.data=$DATA -Epath.logs=$LOGS"

ELASTICSEARCH=$HOME/Development/elastic/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-5.1.1

$ELASTICSEARCH/bin/elasticsearch $BASH_ES_OPTS
```

Notice the options in BASH_ES_OPTS, these are the ones that changes a lot in version 5. My structure is a folder per project with this script and a few folders: config, data and logs. The config folder contains the files from the elastic distribution: elasticsearch.yml, jvm.properties and log4j2.properties.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I am still getting the same error following this. Maybe I'll see if I get the same problems with an older version of ES.

Comment: Did you change other parameters on your system? Maybe a custom .bash_profile? Using tools like zsh?

Comment: Thanks! My .bash_profile was the culprit, specifically this line: `# Force grep to always use the color option and show line numbers`
`export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'` If you add this comment as an answer I can select it as the answer.