# elasticsearch - Could not find or load main class -Xms2g

Tags: java, elasticsearch, homebrew

I installed elasticsearch with homebrew on Mac OSX Sierra (10.12.5).

The installation with homebrew appears successful and brew info states it is installed meeting all prerequisites.

When I go to run the "elasticsearch" command, I get the following error...

```
Error: Could not find or load main class -Xms2g
```

I have tried installing java 1.8 both via homebrew and manually.

I am using java JDK not JRE.

I also tried installing elasticsearch manually, however the installation itself fails with the same exact error.

Any insight would be appreciated.

=== UPDATE ===

Quick answer below.

Additional information can be found here:
[Unable to install Elasticsearch on Mac Sierra (10.12.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149796/unable-to-install-elasticsearch-on-mac-sierra-10-12-2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install Elasticsearch on Mac Sierra (10.12.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41149796/unable-to-install-elasticsearch-on-mac-sierra-10-12-2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have set :

```
export GREP_OPTIONS='--color=always'
```

in your `.bashrc` or somewhere else, it will probably broke shell pipes and causes problems. Try to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

In my instance, it was a mistake when I fill the environment in the docker-compose file. It was like:

```
...
    environment:
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
...
```

So, the docker couldn't set the env properly, then after I recreated the container, it has fixed:

```
...
    environment:
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g"
...
```

Comment: This actually make a difference, I didn't know this

Answer (score 0):

If there is any anti-virus or security scanner tool installed on the host, it may delete the vulnerable packages which are required by elasticsearch. In my case, clamav scanner deleted log4j package on the host machine which is required by elasticsearch. The logs did not indicate anything like that, instead I was getting the following error:

`Error: Could not find or load main class 8-:-Xmx1g Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 8-:-Xmx1g`

The issue was fixed by installing log4j using yum package manager

`yum install log4j`